# Javafx thread free

Tags: javafx, netbeans-8

I need some help. When I run my code the first time and enter the user name and password the data load into my table. However after after when my scene load and I enter a value in the textfield and click on the button to search for that value, my Gui freezes. One more thing I am doing the search through my database.

Here is my main code

```
public class LoginStage extends Application {

    loginB.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
        if (areAllFieldsFilled()){
            if (connectCheck()) {
                playerDao = new PlayerDaoImpl(connect);
                //loginStage.hide();
                GiantsMainStage mainStage = new GiantsMainStage(playerDao);
                loginStage.setScene(mainStage);
                loginStage.setMaximized(true);
       }               
       }
    });


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my second window

```
public class GiantsMainStage extends Scene {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public LoginStage loginStage;

    public GiantsMainStage(PlayerDao dao) {
        super(new BorderPane());
        this.playerDao = dao;
        setUp();
    }

    private void setUp() {
        mainPane = new BorderPane();

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(rankCol, nameCol, posCol, schoolCol, ageCol, warCol);
        players = playerDao.getAllPlayers();
        tableView.setItems(players);

        loaddb.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {

        });

        remove.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            playerDao.deletePlayer(fName.getText());
            players = playerDao.getAllPlayers();
            tableView.setItems(players);
        });

        submit.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            try{
                playerDao.addPlayer(new Player(Integer.parseInt(rank.getText()), 
                        fName.getText(), position.getText(), school.getText(), 
                        Integer.parseInt(age.getText()), Double.parseDouble(war.getText())));
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException ie){

            }
        });

        clearSAF.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (!rank.getText().isEmpty() || !fName.getText().isEmpty() || 
                    !position.getText().isEmpty() || !school.getText().isEmpty() || 
                    !age.getText().isEmpty() || !war.getText().isEmpty()) {
            rank.clear();
            fName.clear();
            position.clear();
            school.setText("");
            age.clear();
            war.clear();
            }
        });

        posWar.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            System.out.println("Button press");
            double wars = Double.parseDouble(war.getText().trim());
            sc.nextLine();
            String get = position.getText().trim();
            players = playerDao.posWar(get, wars);
            players.forEach(p -> System.out.println("This is it\n\n" + p));
            //players.forEach(p -> System.out.println("This is it " + p));
            //tableView.setItems(players);
        });
    }
}
```

For example, if I put in a value in the text field and click on this button the Gui freezes

```
    posWar.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
        System.out.println("Button press");
        double wars = Double.parseDouble(war.getText().trim());
        sc.nextLine();
        String get = position.getText().trim();
        players = playerDao.posWar(get, wars);
        players.forEach(p -> System.out.println("This is it\n\n" + p));
    });
}
```

This class is where I keep all my SQL Statement

```
public PlayerDaoImpl(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

@Override
public ObservableList<Player> getAllPlayers() {
    ObservableList<Player> players = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        statement =  connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "{call list_by_rank ()}";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int rank = resultSet.getInt(1);
            String name = resultSet.getString(2);
            String position = resultSet.getString(3);
            String school = resultSet.getString(4);
            int age = resultSet.getInt(5);
            double war = resultSet.getDouble(6);
            Player player = new Player(rank, name, position, school, age, war);
            players.add(player);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    return players;
}
@Override
public ObservableList<Player> posWar(String position, double war) {

    ObservableList<Player> found = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        String store = "{call pos_and_war" + " ('" + position + "'," + position + ")}";
        cs = connection.prepareCall(store);
        rs = cs.executeQuery();
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

       int colum = rsmd.getColumnCount();

       if (rs.next()) {
           rs.beforeFirst();
           while (rs.next()) {
               for (int i = 1; i < colum + 1; i++) {
                   int rank = rs.getInt(1);
                   String name = rs.getString(2);
                   String positio = rs.getString(3);
                   String school = rs.getString(4);
                   int age = rs.getInt(5);
                   double wars = rs.getInt(6);
                   Player player = new Player(rank, name, positio, school, age, wars);
                   found.add(player);
               }
           }
       } else {
           message.showMessageDialog(null, "nSorry, there is no position or war "
                   + "match " + position + " " + position);
       }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {  
    }
    return found; 
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using the standard input stream for user input in a GUI application? `sc.nextLine()` is going to block, which is why the GUI freezes.

Comment: Now is not freezing thank. But I have another problem. In my database I have a double of 3.5, 5.5 and so on. But when the data load into the table, it make 5.5 into 21.0 and 3.5 into 19.0. Do you know what it's doing that

Comment: This question has been solved. James should add his answer. You should accept it. Then you should ask a new questions.